# Facet not filtering proper data using Solr Slop

Tags: search

I am using facet to filter the solr search result. It's working fine, but if I use solr slop to retrieve data all the records are proper and then try to filter the records using facet Sector, then the result displayed in location facet is improper.

E.g: initially search for England, it retrieves all data of England record include location, Sector Contract type data.Location details are displayed in location facet block. But when I do deep filter using Sector facet (sector records are within location searched I.e. England), I get records from Scotland location too. Scotland location is listed in the location facet along with England. Not knowing what is going wrong after using Solr slop as without it all the data retrieved is properly.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please add an explicit question.